# Float and Math precision on different systems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, floating-accuracy

I want to implement a gameplay recording feature in a project, which would only record player input and seed of the RNG at the beginning of the level. Then I could take such record and play it on my computer in order to test it for validity.

I'm only concerned with some numerical differences which might appear between different Flash Player version, Operating Systems or CPUs (or whatever else that might be affected). The project would be written for Flash Player 10.0.0+. What stuff I am concerned with:

- Operations on Numbers: Multiplying, dividing; bit operations (possibly bit shifting too); addition and subtraction; modulo
- Math class: sin, cos and atan2; rounding
- localToGlobal/globalToLocal with rotations and scaling

I won't be using stuff like hitTest, getObjectsUnderPoint, hitTestPoint, getBounds and so on, all collisions will be geometrical.

So, are there any chances that using any of the pointed things above will yield different results on different systems? If so, what can I do to avoid them?

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question...

It's not a "will this game play the same on multiple platforms", it's "will a recording of user inputs produce the exact same output when simulated" question.

My gut would say "don't worry about it the flash VM abstracts the differences away", but then as I think more, there are some areas that might be a problem.

First, I wouldn't record anything time-based.  A user hitting a key at 1.21 seconds in might be tough to predict whether that happens before or after a frame's worth of computation, especially if either the recording or playback computer was under load.  Trying to time tweens with user input is probably a recipe for failure.

Accuracy of floating point should be ok.  The algorithms that define when to round are well documented in IEEE-754, and all VM's use 64 bit Numbers regardless of OS they're running on.  I'm guessing the math operations are equally understood.

I think it's good to avoid hitTest and whatnot.  I imagine they theoretically could be influenced by whether or not hardware acceleration is being used.  But I'm not an expert there, so maybe not.

Now localToGlobal/globalToLocal... I just don't know.  They might have that theoretical hardware acceleration problem, but I tend to doubt it.

So I guess I didn't give any real answers.

Comment: About timing that's not a problem, as I am not using delta. I think I will then just prepare some test and post it somewhere to get data. Thanks anyway :).

Answer (score 1):

Trig functions WILL NOT WORK! You must create custom implementations of the following: acos, asin, atan, atan2, cos, exp, log, pow, sin, and sqrt.  And obviously, random().

I'm still in the process of testing the Number class.  I can't say for sure whether additon/subtraction/etc. will be consistent on every machine.

Comment: Any other information? I suppose the trigs are unreliable, because these are computated by CPU? At least I remember, many years ago, reading that these are usually done by CPU, and it is unsure how each will handle it. Random is not a problem as I would be using custom implementation of Marsenne Twister anyway, but I am still interested in the Number behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely (although possible) that things will behave in a noticeably different way on different computers.  Even if they did, it would be a very rare event and not something I would recommend worrying about unless it is absolutely crucial to gameplay.

Comment: Not for gameplay but rather for checking if a user is cheating or not, and it would be difficult to check that if, let's say, because of some Floats related incompatibilities, the player fell to the pit right at the beginning of the stage instead of jumping from the last half-a-pixel effectively breaking the whole replay and making it impossible for me to validate :).

Comment: I believe these occurrences would be sufficiently rare that it wouldn't have an effect.  I would build out the engine and not worry about it for now, and when you are done test it by playing through many times and ensuring the player ends at the same position (within say 0.01 units) in both the actual game and the simulation.  If they don't, then you can isolate the problem, but I would be very surprised if rounding differences of Number (double precision, 64 bits) ever came into play.

Comment: I also doubt, but I learned that sometimes trusting your gut on never before tested things can lead up to major problems. I am primarily concerned with trigonometry functions tho'.